# Blank fields in HTML form every time I refresh

Tags: php, html, forms, page-refresh

I know this question has been asked thousands of times, but I can't find a solution for my case. I try to stablish connection with database ONLY when submit button is pressed and none of the fields are blank. But blank rows keep appearing after every refresh. And also, rows with content duplicate after every refresh if I don't submit the form again. It seems like $_POST keeps the data through refreshes if I don't 'renew' it with a form submition.

Here is my code. I'll really REALLY apreciate any help.

```
<?php
$nombre = $titulo = $texto = $fecha = "";
$mensajeEnvio = $mensajeError = ""; 

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if ((isset($_POST["submit-comentario"])) && (!empty($_POST["nombre"])) && (!empty($_POST["titulo"])) && (!empty($_POST["texto"]))){

        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
        $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
        $texto=$_POST['texto'];

        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO foro (usuario_comentario, titulo_comentario, fecha_comentario, texto_comentario) VALUES ('$usuario', '$titulo', '$fecha', '$texto')";
        }

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            $mensajeEnvio= "Tu comentario se ha enviado correctamente. ¡Gracias por participar!";
        } else {
            $mensajeError= "Ha habido un problema. Por favor, vuelve a publicar tu comentario. ";   
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
} else {
    $mensajeError= "Por favor, rellena todos los campos y vuelve a publicar."; 
}
```

And here is the form, which comes right after the php code.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>" id="formulario-foro">
    <input name="nombre" type="text" id="usuario" placeholder="Nombre" /><br>
    <textarea name="titulo" style="width: 100%; height: 23px"id="titulo" placeholder="Título" /></textarea><br>
    <textarea name="texto" style="width: 100%; height: 150px" placeholder=" Tu comentario..." id="texto" /></textarea><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="fecha" id="fecha" value="<?php echo $mysqldate?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit-comentario" value="Publicar">  
    <div class="mensaje-envio"><?php echo $mensajeEnvio; ?></div> 
    <div class="mensaje-error"><?php echo $mensajeError; ?></div> 
</form>
```

Comment: refreshing the page after a submit actually CAN resend the data. the browser should notify you and ask for behavior...

Comment: *It seems like $_POST keeps the data through refreshes* ... umm, yes, it does - you'll normally get a pop-up warning though.

Comment: I get the pop-up, but I can't refresh the page if I don't accept, so I end up doing it. I'd like to send data ONLY when 'submit' button is pressed. ¿Is that possible?

Comment: You just posted your website's url with the admin name and password... edit it out for your own safety and change password on your site ASAP

Comment: *"I try to stablish connection with database ONLY when submit button is pressed"* - Then move `if ((isset($_POST["submit-comentario"])) && (!empty($_POST["nombre"])) && (!empty($_POST["titulo"])) && (!empty($_POST["texto"]))){` above the line where you connect to, or use another conditional statement placed above the DB connection for the submit button only. There are many ways to do this.

Comment: Also `if ((isset($_POST["submit-comentario"])) && (!empty($_POST["nombre"])) && (!empty($_POST["titulo"])) && (!empty($_POST["texto"]))){` can be cut down to simply `if (isset($_POST["submit-comentario"]) && !empty($_POST["nombre"]) && !empty($_POST["titulo"]) && !empty($_POST["texto"]))` - you have too many brackets for nothing.

Comment: Fred, the database connetion is wrapped inside this if statement, I don't think I can put it closer... And as for the conditional for the submit button, I only know the isset, any other suggestions that might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session keys to check.

For that first you need to create a random session key and store it in a session variable. Also provide this value as a hidden element in your form.
During the insertion you can check whether the value in hidden element is same as the session key, then insert. Else through error message. After successful insertion reset the session key again.

place this at the php start

`session_start();function get_session_key(){$randomId=microtime(true).uniqid();
$_SESSION['unique_id']=$randomId;
return $randomId;
}`

then change your if condition to

`if ((isset($_POST["submit-comentario"])) && (!empty($_POST["nombre"])) && (!empty($_POST["titulo"])) && (!empty($_POST["texto"]))&&$_SESSION['unique_id']==$_POST['unique_id']){`

After insertion add the below line.

`if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            //Reset the seeion key
            $_SESSION['unique_id'] = "";`

Then add the following line in your form

`<input type="hidden" name="unique_id" value="<?php echo get_session_key();?>"/>`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm just starting with php so I don't know if I'll be able to do it. I'll let you know. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Hi user3535945. After aplying this changes, the page seemed to work, but no new rows are being saved in my database as  $_SESSION['unique_id'] and $_POST['unique_id'] are different.  Here is my code:

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this small hack,

```
      <form action="" method='POST'  
onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent refreshes in my opinion is the following:

1. User submits form
2. Put all POST data into a SESSION variable

   $_SESSION['post_data'] = $_POST;
3. Unset the $_POST data

   unset($_POST);
4. Redirect to same/new page and check for the SESSION['post_data'] instaed of $_POST

   if (isset($_SESSION['post_data']) && is_array($_SESSION['post_data']) && count($_SESSION['post_data'])>0) {
       // ... Do your Query
       unset($_SESSION['post_data']);
       // Redirect
       header("Location: ....");

   }

This way your users will not be able to refresh and re-post the form. And when they use the previous button, the form will be empty and $_POST will not be filled.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a POST-to-GET redirect after you have successfully saved the data in the database. That way, if the user refreshes the page, he refreshes the GET request and not the POST that was used to store the information.

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    // Success!
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    // Prevent further processing
    return;
} else {
    $mensajeError= "Ha habido un problema. Por favor, vuelve a publicar tu comentario. ";   
}
```

Of course you could also redirect to another page and/or add something to show a message (either using the session, or via a GET parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your ideas. I finally solved this problem, that were actually two problems.

First, I used user3535945 suggestion of sessions to prevent rows from duplicating at every refresh after sending the forms.

But blank rows kept appearing untill I found out that I was stablishing another database connection in a page that was subordinated to this one in my wordpress hyerarchy and was sending blank form data to mysql. I deleted the page and now every thing works fine!!!

It is a stupid mistake but I wanted to leave it here in case it helps someone else.